# Can't swipe ViewPager that is the content of a Scaffold with Drawer in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `Scaffold` with drawer and a content containing a `ViewPager`.

```
Scaffold(
    drawerLayout = { MyDrawer() },
) { innerPadding ->
   // Content with ViewPager
}
```

When I swipe the screen to change the page of the ViewPager, it instead opens the drawer. Can I disable this behavior and only open the drawer when swiped from the left-most part of the screen?

I tried setting `gesturesEnabled` of the Scaffold to false, but this also disables the swipe from the side of the screen.

Comment: I believe it's an issue of `Scaffold` that's why I've created an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197284187). I was able to help in same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68773210/3585796) by creating an invisible box with padding, but this was only possible because all touch handling was done in our code and I was able to add padding before touch handling. In case with custom view this isn't possible, so lets wait for a solution from mainteiners